# Using reflection on generics recursively

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseDataEntity
{
    private List<string> _Changes = new List<string>();

    public IEnumerable<string> GetChanges()
    {
        return _Changes;
    }

    public bool HasDataChanged
    {
        get { return (GetChanges().Count() > 0); }
    }

    public bool HasChildRecords
    {
        get { return (GetType().GetChildRecords().Count() > 0); }
    }
}

public class ChildRecords : IList<T> where T : BaseDataEntity
{

}
```

And a few helper methods:

```
public static PropertyInfo[] GetChildRecords(this Type aType)
{
    return aType.GetProperties().Where(pi => pi.IsChildRecords()).ToArray();
}

public static bool IsChildRecords(this PropertyInfo info)
{
    return (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ChildRecordsAttribute), false).Length > 0);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is implement a property called HaveChildRecordsChanged using reflection. My question is how would I go about using reflection to check the HasDataChanged property of all ChildRecords of arbitrary depth?

I tried something like:

```
var isChanged = false;

foreach (var info in GetType().GetChildRecords())
{
    var childRecordObject = info.GetValue(this, null);
    var childRecords = childRecordObject as ChildRecords<BaseDataEntity>;   //cannot unbox this, it evaluates as null
    if (null != childRecords && childRecords.Any(x => x.HasDataChanged))
    {
        isChanged = true;   //never hit
    }
}

return isChanged;
```

Comment: Why do you believe you need to use Reflection?

Comment: Because I don't know the concrete type at design time.

Comment: From my own experience, abstracting that far with reflection will bite you hard in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChildRecords<T>` is generic so `ChildRecords<Company>` can't be cast to `ChildRecords<BaseDataEntity>`.

Since you already filter the property marked with the `ChildRecordsAttribute` the simplest solution would be to cast to `IEnumerable` and use `OfType<BaseDataEntity>()`

```
var childRecords = childRecordObject as IEnumerable; // IList<T> will be IEnumerable
if (null != childRecords && childRecords.OfType<BaseDataEntity>().Any(x => x.HasDataChanged))
{
    isChanged = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! When I was trying different approaches I had tried casting childRecordObject as IList, but this still evalulated a null. Why would this evaluate to null but be okay when casting to IEnumerable?

Comment: `IList<T>` does not inherit `IList`. `IList<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>` which inherits `IEnumerable`. So if you implement `IList<T>` you implement `IEnumerable` but not `IList`

Comment: Ah! Thanks, that makes sense.